# How can prove this $\sum_{k=0}^{p}\binom{p}{k}(\pm i\sqrt{3})^k\equiv 1\pm (i\sqrt{3})^p-p\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{(\mp i\sqrt{3})^k}{k}\pmod{p^2}?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For any prime $p>3$ show that 
>   $$p\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\dfrac{(-3)^j}{2j+1}\equiv \left(\dfrac{p}{3}\right)\pmod{p^2}$$
>   where $\left(\dfrac{p}{3}\right)$ denotes the Legendre symbol.

This is proof: we have 
$$(1\pm i\sqrt{3})^p=2^pe^{\pm i\pi p/3}=2^p(\cos{(\pi p/3)}\pm i\sin{(\pi p/3)}=2^{p-1}\left(1\pm i\left(\dfrac{p}{3}\right)\sqrt{3}\right)$$
On the other hand we have
\begin{align*}
(1\pm i\sqrt{3})^p=\sum_{k=0}^{p}\binom{p}{k}(\pm i\sqrt{3})^k&\equiv 1\pm (i\sqrt{3})^p-p\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\dfrac{(\mp i\sqrt{3})^k}{k}\\
&\equiv 1\pm i\sqrt{3}(-3)^{(p-1)/2}-S_{0}\pm i\sqrt{3}S_{1}\pmod{p^2}
\end{align*}
where 
$$S_{0}=p\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\dfrac{(-3)^j}{2j},S_{1}=p\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{p-3}{2}}\dfrac{(-3)^j}{2j+1}$$
then 
$$S_{0}\equiv 1-2^{p-1}\pmod{p^2}, S_{1}\equiv 2^{p-1}\left(\dfrac{p}{3}\right)-(-3)^{(p-1)/2}\pmod{p^2}$$
so
\begin{align*}
p\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\dfrac{(-3)^j}{2j+1}&=p\sum_{j=0}^{(p-3)/2}\dfrac{(-3)^j}{2j+1}+(-3)^{(p-1)/2}+(-3)^{(p-1)/2}p\sum_{j=1}^{(p-1)/2}\dfrac{(-3)^j}{p+2j}\\
&\equiv S_{1}+(-3)^{(p-1)/2}+(-3)^{(p-1)/2}S_{0}\\
&\equiv (2^{p-1}-1)\left(\left(\dfrac{p}{3}\right)-(-3)^{(p-1)/2}\right)+\left(\dfrac{p}{3}\right)\\
&\equiv \left(\dfrac{p}{3}\right)\pmod{p^2}
\end{align*}
where use
$$p|(2^{p-1}-1),2|\left(\left(\dfrac{p}{3}\right)-(-3)^{(p-1)/2}\right)$$

---

My question:

(1)：why $$\sum_{k=0}^{p}\binom{p}{k}(\pm i\sqrt{3})^k\equiv 1\pm (i\sqrt{3})^p-p\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\dfrac{(\mp i\sqrt{3})^k}{k}\pmod{p^2}?$$
(2):
why 
$$S_{0}\equiv 1-2^{p-1}\pmod{p^2}, S_{1}\equiv 2^{p-1}\left(\dfrac{p}{3}\right)-(-3)^{(p-1)/2}\pmod{p^2}?$$

Thank you someone can solve my two problem,Thank you very much,and this 
$$p\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\dfrac{(-3)^j}{2j+1}\equiv \left(\dfrac{p}{3}\right)\pmod{p^2}$$
have other methods? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Now,I have konw why 
$$S_{0}\equiv 1-2^{p-1}\pmod {p^2},S_{1}\equiv 2^{p-1}\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)-(-3)^{(p-1)/2}\pmod {p^2}$$

Because use 
$$(1\pm i\sqrt{3})^p=2^{p-1}(1\pm i\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)\sqrt{3})$$
and other hand we have
$$(1\pm i\sqrt{3})^p\equiv 1\pm i\sqrt{3}(-3)^{(p-1)/2}-S_{0}\pm i\sqrt{3}S_{1}\pmod{p^2}$$
so we have done